# How we chaage style/CSS at runtime in flex?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

I need to change the style/CSS/SKINs of all components when application run in browser or AIR ?

My application includes built-in and custom components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[StyleManager.setStyle(name:String, style:Object)](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/managers/StyleManager.html#setStyle%28%29)

[StyleManager.setComponentStyle(component:Object, name:String, style:Object)](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/managers/StyleManager.html#setComponentStyle%28%29)